# CheckBoxes for Crystal Report VS2012 VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

How to create crystal report with multiple check boxes per question.
Example:

Question 1?            Yes        No       None
Question 2?            Yes        No       None
.
.
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a formula and set the true portion as the character that creates a checked box in wingdings, and the false to the unchecked box in wingdings.  then when you drag the field onto the form select wingdings as the font

See the link below, this will give you the basis of the formula you need:
[Check box in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279907/checkbox-in-a-crystal-report)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.. Can you give me code snippet on how to do it.